# How can I install both 32bit and 64bit LibreOffice?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, libreoffice, 32-bit

I have a new Windows 10 computer. I'm trying to install LibreOffice on it. I have a couple of legacy 32-bit only ODBC database drivers that I still need to use, plus some drivers that are 64-bit. So, in order to interface with ODBC, I need both the 32-bit and the 64-bit versions of LibreOffice installed.

The problem is that, when I install one version, it notices that the other version is already installed and "helpfully" (rolls eyes) uninstalls it for me. I can't find any way to get around it.

I know that it's possible, because I was using an old Windows 7 computer that had both versions installed. But I can't remember how I did it. (Or maybe they've changed their installer in the meantime?)

So, any ideas?

Comment: Did you try a custom install into a different directory?

Comment: If LibreOffice is anything like Office it's actually NOT possible to have both 32-bit and 64-bit of the same version installed on a system

Comment: @DavidPostill It was already installing in a different directory from the other version ("C:\Program Files" vs. "C:\Program Files (x86)"). Just for testing I installed it in a completely different directory, and it still removed the other version without asking or even warning me.

Comment: @Ramhound I know for a fact that it was possible at one time, because, as I said in my original post, I had both versions on another computer.

Comment: The LibreOffice 64-bit installer will automatically uninstall the 32-bit version. But it might perhaps be possible if installing the 64-bit version first, using different folders. Otherwise, the solution might be to use LibreOffice Portable, which I believe is 32-bit.

Comment: @harrymc I tried it both ways, the 32-bit version will silently uninstall the 64-bit version and vice-versa. (Well, I say "silently"; it does tell you that it's doing so **as** it does so, but doesn't warn you ahead of time.)

Comment: The Portable version might help. Otherwise a virtual machine is required.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I **did** read what he said about the portable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LibreOffice 64-bit installer will automatically uninstall the
32-bit version and vice versa, so it's probably impossible to have both
versions installed in the classical sense.

I can see two options:

- Use
  [LibreOffice Portable](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/portable-versions/)
  that can work with the PortableApps.com platform or work by itself from
  a local drive. I believe that this version is in 32-bit format,
  so the installed version should be the 64-bit one.
- Use a virtual machine to install in it the other version.

Comment: Thanks, the portable version worked. I'll wait a minute to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have 64-bit LibreOffice and 32-bit Apache OpenOffice installed on the same machine. No special steps are needed to do this on Windows.

I use LibreOffice for nearly everything but keep AOO as a backup in case something I need doesn't work in recent versions of LO. In most ways, AOO is like an older version of LO. AOO keeps to earlier compatibilities such as Python 2 for macros instead of Python 3.